# Created a rawQuery method in DatabseHelper but can't reffrence that in MainActivity, WHY?

Tags: java, android-studio

I have created a method to do rawQuery which returns a List. But it seems it can't be referenced in
feedBackAct. Can anyone Help me?

This is my method in DatabaseHelper Class:

```java
public List<userFeedBackModel> getAll(){
        List<userFeedBackModel> list = new ArrayList<>();

        String doQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + FEEDBACKS_TABLE;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

         Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(doQuery, null);
         if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
             do {
                //loop through the cursor to create an object for each report
                 int userId = cursor.getInt(0);
                 int roll = cursor.getInt(1);
                 String name = cursor.getString(2);
                 String tech = cursor.getString(3);
                 String contact = cursor.getString(4);
                 String description = cursor.getString(5);
                 userFeedBackModel userFeedBack = new userFeedBackModel(userId,roll,name,tech,contact,description);

                 list.add(userFeedBack);
             }
             while (cursor.moveToNext());
         }
         else {
             //do nothing
         }
         cursor.close();
         db.close();
         return list;
     }
```

this is the code where I am trying to access the `getAll()` method but it says Can't resolve this method

```java
btnViewList.setOnClickListener(v ->{
            DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(feedBackAct.this);
            List<userFeedBackModel> viewAll = new databaseHelper.getAll();

            Toast.makeText(feedBackAct.this, viewAll.toString(), toastLength).show();
        });
```

Comment: Try this instead `DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());`!

Comment: That doesn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line

```
List<userFeedBackModel> viewAll = new databaseHelper.getAll();
```

Just delete the new and you good to go

```
List<userFeedBackModel> viewAll = databaseHelper.getAll();
```